# Regex removing contents inside last bracket

Tags: java, regex

I have input text such as:

```
Text (Some Other Text) (More Text)
```

What I'm trying to do is completely remove the last brackets as well as the text inside it. IE `(More Text)`
In more general terms, I want an expression to only match the last bracket and contents.

I have tested quite a few variations of the following regex `\s\(.*?\)$` but I cannot seem to get it working, I can tell that the . operator is matching the first bracket all the way through the last closing bracket but whatever I've tried I can't seem to think of how to approach this.

I'm using the Java implementation of regex. (Omitting the extra escape character in the above)

Comment: Try using `\s\([^)]+\)$`

Comment: Ahhh I see, thanks for that. I had a similar solution at one stage except I didn't have the + after the [^)], just tested and it works with the * as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args){ 
        String reg = "\\s\\([^)]+\\)$";
        String text = "Text (Some Other Text) (More Text)";
        System.out.println(text.replaceAll(reg, ""));
}
```

Output :

```
Text (Some Other Text)
```

**EDIT :**
If you have some extra text after the last brackets, @anubhava provided a good solution

Comment: Doesn't work if input text is `"Text (Some Other Text) (More Text) foo"`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks to notice that, +1 for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Following should work for you:

```
String regex = "\\s+\\([^)]+\\)([^()]*)$";
String text  = "Text (Some Other Text) (More Text) foo";
String repl  = text.replaceAll(regex, "$1");    
// Text (Some Other Text) foo
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/WnUeIQ

**OR Using Positive Lookahead**

```
String regex = "\\s+\\([^)]+\\)(?=[^()]*$)";
String text  = "Text (Some Other Text) (More Text) foo";
String repl  = text.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/2HRBf0

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    String s = "Text (Some Other Text) (More Text)";
    s = s.replaceAll(".*\\((.+)\\)$", "$1");
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
More Text
```

Answer (score 0):

If your text will always be in that format, you don't need regex for this, it's inefficient.

This is fine, and will be faster than regex:

```
String s = "Text (Some Other Text) (More Text)";
s = s.substring(0,s.lastIndexOf('('));
System.out.println(s);
```